# hiding Posts count in all category page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

how may I hide the post counts in all category page suppose

```
List A
  Category A (2)
  Category B (3)
```

just to keep Category A

Comment: what post counts ?? add some code for us

Comment: Are you using a widget here or do you have some code you can post?